# How to get the exact div positioning using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to calculate the div positioning. This is my code .

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
.content {width: 60%;
 position: relative;
  text-align: center ; 
    top: 150px;    
    left:300px;
    right:450px; border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="content">
Testings content
</div>


<script>
    function ReadDivPos() {
            var content = document.getElementsByClassName('content');

            for (i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
                console.log("Top " + content[i].getBoundingClientRect().top) //top
                console.log("left " + content[i].getBoundingClientRect().left) //left
                console.log("right " + content[i].getBoundingClientRect().right) //right
                console.log("offsetWidth " + content[i].offsetWidth); //width
            }
            var _divPos = "LEft "+content[0].getBoundingClientRect().left + ",Width " + content[0].offsetWidth + ",Avail Width " + window.screen.availWidth + ",Right " + content[0].getBoundingClientRect().right;
            return _divPos;
        }
        console.log(ReadDivPos());

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This code works fine when the page is not resized but when the page is resized and horizontal scroll bar appears on the screen then it doesnot work fine. How can i get the exact positions of the div if the page is resized or not. For example these are the images i have captured to explain the problem .

When the page is resized and scroll bar is at the extreme right then left positioning of div shows 208px which is wrong and it should be 311 px .
[image: When scroll bar is on the extreme right]

When i move the scroller on the left and then i calculated the width using Chrome MeasureIT add on then it says 311px.

[image]
[image: When scroll bar is on the extreme left]

I want to get the exact positioning of the div.I am using class of the div to get the positioning as i am not using div id and i only had to use the class so this is how i have done it but it is not working when the page is resized. Any help?

Comment: You have to add a `jQuery()` callback that captures the resize event and adjust the position then.

Comment: well i am doing this and this is not the original code as i have using  win.addEventListener("resize", function(event) { to get the positions when the page is resized but the point is the div is not calculating properly when the page is not maximized and scroll bar is at the right.

Comment: Did you try various browsers to see whether it does the same in all of them?

Comment: yes even you can try the code on chrome. just change the size of the page and move the scroll bar to the right then right click the page and reload it. YOu will see the same problem do not refresh the page by pressing f5 because by default scroller will be on the left side and positioning will be fine but to see the problem scoller should be at the right side and it is only possible by right click reload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have jQuery loading in the page, take a look at the jQuery [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) and [position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/) methods and leverage jQuery selectors.

```
<script>
    function ReadDivPos(selector) {
        var _divPos = "";

        $(selector).each(function() {
            var p = $(this).offset();
            var w = $(this).width();
            console.log("Top " + p.top) //top
            console.log("left " + p.left) //left
            console.log("right " + p.left + w) //right
            console.log("offsetWidth " + w); //width

            _divPos += "Left " + p.left + ",Width " + w + ",Avail Width " + window.screen.availWidth + ",Right " + (p.left + w) + "\\n";
        });
        return _divPos;
    }

    console.log(ReadDivPos(".content"));
</script>
```