# Calculating positioning of the parent Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi i want to calculate the position of the Div. Pardon me if i am not able to explain it properly but i will try to explain everything in the simplest way. I am creating sidepanel ad and to place the panels i want the position of the width. When i upload the script on my server then i get a small script which we place on the publisher website and where our script runs inside the iframe. I want to get the position of the div which has a class 'content'. Here is the screen shot.

[image: Screnshot 1]

in the above screenshot the yellow highlighted script is calculating the position of the div class="content" which is in red box. My code was working fine but on the publisher site it was not working fine and i was only able to get only two Divs whose id is like ebDiv..... (these divs are above the yellow highlighted js).

Then i found out to read the parentDiv in order to get the content positions.

i wrote this code.

```
 var parentDoc = window;
        while (parentDoc !== parentDoc.parent) {
            parentDoc = parentDoc.parent;
        }
        parentDoc = parentDoc.document;
        var parentDiv = parentDoc.getElementsByTagName('div');
        var divs = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < parentDiv.length; i++) {
            if (parentDiv[i].className == "content") {
       alert(parentDiv[i].offsetWidth);
       alert(parentDiv[i].offsetLeft);
      }
```

The width is calcuated as 1010 which is fine but i am just missing left positioning which i am getting using parentDiv[i].offsetLeft is 2.

[image: Screetshot 2]

Above the screenshot has width 1010 which is fine but left positioning is not correct.

i had this code to calculate the width.

```
function ReadDivPos(selector) {
        var _divPos = "";

        $(selector).each(function() {
            var p = $(this).offset();
            var w = $(this).width();
            console.log("Top " + p.top) //top
            console.log("left " + p.left) //left
            console.log("right " + p.left + w) //right
            console.log("offsetWidth " + w); //width

            _divPos += "Left " + p.left + ",Width " + w + ",Avail Width " + window.screen.availWidth + ",Right " + (p.left + w) + "\\n";
        });
        return _divPos;
    }
console.log(ReadDivPos(".content"));
```

when i am using the same code to calculate the positioning then it is not working .

```
                 var parentDoc = window;
                 while (parentDoc !== parentDoc.parent) {
                    parentDoc = parentDoc.parent;
                }
                parentDoc = parentDoc.document;
                var parentDiv = parentDoc.getElementsByTagName('div');
                var divs = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < parentDiv.length; i++) {
                    if (parentDiv[i].className == "content") {
                   $(parentDiv[i]).each(function() {
                    var p = $(this).offset();
                    var w = $(this).width();
                    console.log("Top " + p.top) //top
                    console.log("left " + p.left) //left
                    console.log("right " + p.left + w) //right
                    console.log("offsetWidth " + w); //width

                    _divPos += "Left " + p.left + ",Width " + w + ",Avail Width " +          window.screen.availWidth + ",Right " + (p.left + w) + "\\n";

    }

  }
```

Can someone me explain me how to fix this. Jquery/Javascript anythingwould be fine. I am not good in the frontend things so i am sorry if i could not explain it better. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function used to get the position on the page of an element:

```
    function getPosition(element) {
        var xPosition = 0;
        var yPosition = 0;

        while (element) {
            xPosition += (element.offsetLeft - element.scrollLeft + element.clientLeft);
            yPosition += (element.offsetTop - element.scrollTop + element.clientTop);
            element = element.offsetParent;
        }
        return { x: xPosition, y: yPosition };
    }
```

Used like this:

```
var pos = getPosition(element);
var x = pos["x"];
var y = pos["y"];
```

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you need, but if not maybe you can tweak it to fit your situation

Comment: i tried this var pos = getPosition(parentDiv[i]);var x = pos["x"]; this is working but now i am having this issue again (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27715056/how-to-get-the-exact-div-positioning-using-jquery-javascript?noredirect=1#comment43842847_27715056)